# Testing library `within` return type in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have the following helpers for my tests with React & testing library :

```
const getSomething = (name: string, container: Screen | any = screen) {
  return container.getByRole('someRole', { name: name })
}
```

The `container` is either the `screen` from react testing, but it can also come from testing library :

```
const myParentElement = screen.getByRole('cell', { name: 'foo' })
const myElement = getSomething("myName", within(myParentElement))
```

How can I replace the `any` from `container: Screen | any` with the appropriate type returned by `within` ?

*Note: `within` is an alias for `getQueriesForElement`, which is defined [here](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/main/types/get-queries-for-element.d.ts#L178-L182) on testing-library*

Comment: How about `container: Screen | ReturnType<typeof getQueriesForElement>` ?

Comment: Just simple as that ! I can't believe I didn't think of it :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jayatubi metioned, `ReturnType<typeof within>` should work.

```
import { within, screen, Screen } from '@testing-library/react';

const getSomething = (name: string, container: Screen | ReturnType<typeof within> = screen) => {
  return container.getByRole('someRole', { name: name });
};

const myParentElement = screen.getByRole('cell', { name: 'foo' });
const myElement = getSomething('myName', within(myParentElement));
```

package version:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
"typescript": "^5.3.2",
```